# Split String by last occurence

Tags: vb.net, string, split, lastindexof

I have a String like this:

> www.myserver.net/Files/Pictures/2014/MyImage.jpg

And I want to split it, so I get the Substring after the last occurence of /.
Which means I like to get MyImage.jpg
I tried it like this:

```
  MsgBox(URL.Substring(URL.LastIndexOf("/"), URL.Length - 1))
```

But that wont work. Can someone help me out how to do this in VB.Net?
C# is also okay, after I've understood the logic, I can convert it myself.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`System.IO.Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
Dim path = "www.myserver.net/Files/Pictures/2014/MyImage.jpg"
Dim filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path) ' MyImage.jpg
```

For the sake of completeness, you could also use `String.Split` or `String.Substring`:

```
filename = path.Split("/"c).Last()
' or 
Dim lastIndex = path.LastIndexOf("/")
If lastIndex >= 0 Then
    fileName = path.Substring(lastIndex + 1)
End If
```

But it is more error-prone and less readable.