# Get a part of string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to get a part of an string in C#
My string is:

```
svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/MBackingBean.java
```

and I want this part of string:

```
svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/
```

How can I get the above?

Comment: You can get guidance from this topic: [Split string by last occurrence][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630592/split-string-by-last-occurence

Answer (score 2):

Try this with [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string str = "svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/MBackingBean.java";
str = str.Substring(0,str.LastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this with [String.Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string s = "svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/MBackingBean.java";
Console.WriteLine(s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf('/'))+"/");
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/18ARgU)

Comment: returned string will `"svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class"` and not `"svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/"`

Comment: change line `Console.WriteLine(s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf('/')+"/");` to `Console.WriteLine(s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf('/'))+"/");`

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do that:

```
string str = "svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/MBackingBean.java";
string s = Regex.Match(str, ".*/").Value;
```

Comment: alternate yes, but unadvisable. Regex is ugly.

Comment: @JoshW Regex clearly shows your intents, you can understand immediately that you want _everything until last / including it_.